Getting 401, when trying to triggered power automate(Http triggered) flow from streamlit app
I have tried below code to triggered the power automate flow:
def get_access_token_powerAutomate():
    tenant_id = os.getenv("TENANT_ID")
    client_id = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
    client_secret = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
    scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
   
    url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
   
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
   
    body = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'scope': scope
    }
   
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
   
    if response.status_code == 200:
        access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
        if not access_token:
            st.error("Access token not found in the response.")
            return None
        return access_token
    else:
        st.error("Failed to obtain access token.")
        st.error(f"Response status: {response.status_code}")
        st.error(f"Response content: {response.content}")
        return None
 
def power_automateflow(organizer_upn, attendee_upns, meeting_notes, selected_subject, transcript_date):
    access_token = get_access_token_powerAutomate()
    st.write("access_token",access_token)
    if not access_token:
        st.error("Access token retrieval failed.")
        return
   
    mail_subject = f" Notes of {selected_subject} on {transcript_date}"
    # Data to be sent
    transcript_data = {
        'organizer_upn': organizer_upn,
        'attendee_upns': attendee_upns,
        'meeting_notes': meeting_notes,
        'mail_subject': mail_subject
    }
 
    # Set the headers with the access token
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
 
    # Power Automate flow endpoint URL
    power_automate_url = os.getenv("POWER_AUTOMATE_URL")
    if not power_automate_url:
        st.error("Power Automate URL is not set.")
        return
 
    # Making the POST request to Power Automate flow
    response = requests.post(power_automate_url, headers=headers, json=transcript_data)
 
    if response.status_code == 200:
        st.success("Meeting Notes sent successfully for organizer's approval!")
        st.success("Check your mail once they approve.")
    else:
        st.error(f"Failed to send Meeting Notes. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        st.error(f"Response content: {response.content}")

I have added below permissions in registered app:

getting below errors:
Failed to send Meeting Notes. Status code: 401 Response content: b'{"error":{"code":"SecurityTokenInvalidSignature","message":"The provided authentication token is not valid, token signature is not properly formatted."}}',
any help will be thankful.
I have try the above code , and wanted to resolved mention issue.

See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/521#issuecomment-577400515, try updating your client_id to [CLIENT_ID]/.default

Can you also include Power Automate flow endpoint URL and the API you are trying to call?

And you are making use of Client credential flow and hence you need to grant Application type API permissions

Hi @Rukmini, here is endpoint URL "https://prod-126.westus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/4799350cbc324bc3863f6885d69abd07/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01", and let me know what Application type API permissions are required.

@Pam Grant OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All  application type API permissions is required. Can you try granting it and check if it resolves the issue

And can you also include the Graph API call you are tying to call?

@Pam Did it work by  granting application type API permission?

Hi @SamNseir, I have made the changes , scope = f'{client_id}/.default', but getting
this error: "code":"MisMatchingOAuthClaims","message":"One or more claims either missing or does not match with the open authentication access control policy."

@Rukmini, after adding permissions and making changes suggested by SamNseir,  I am getting below error : "code":"MisMatchingOAuthClaims","message":"One or more claims either missing or does not match with the open authentication access control policy.

Pass scope as https://service.flow.microsoft.com//.default as scope

And add this power automate api permission in the Azure ad application

@Rukmini, it worked ,now flow is triggering, thanks!

To trigger the power automate (Http triggered) flow from streamlit app, you need to give API permissions of Power automate API

While calling the Power automate API the aud must be https://service.flow.microsoft.com not Microsoft Graph API.

Create a Microsoft Entra ID application and add API permissions like below:

The 401 error usually occurs if the access token does not contain required API permissions to call the API.
To resolve the error, pass scope as https://service.flow.microsoft.com//.default
Modify the code like below:
def get_access_token_powerAutomate():
    tenant_id = os.getenv("TENANT_ID")
    client_id = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
    client_secret = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
    scope = 'https://service.flow.microsoft.com//.default'
   
    url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
   
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
   
    body = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'scope': scope
    }
   
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
   
    if response.status_code == 200:
        access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
        if not access_token:
            st.error("Access token not found in the response.")
            return None
        return access_token
    else:
        st.error("Failed to obtain access token.")
        st.error(f"Response status: {response.status_code}")
        st.error(f"Response content: {response.content}")
        return None
 
def power_automateflow(organizer_upn, attendee_upns, meeting_notes, selected_subject, transcript_date):
    access_token = get_access_token_powerAutomate()
    st.write("access_token",access_token)
    if not access_token:
        st.error("Access token retrieval failed.")
        return
   
    mail_subject = f" Notes of {selected_subject} on {transcript_date}"
    # Data to be sent
    transcript_data = {
        'organizer_upn': organizer_upn,
        'attendee_upns': attendee_upns,
        'meeting_notes': meeting_notes,
        'mail_subject': mail_subject
    }
 
    # Set the headers with the access token
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
 
    # Power Automate flow endpoint URL
    power_automate_url = os.getenv("POWER_AUTOMATE_URL")
    if not power_automate_url:
        st.error("Power Automate URL is not set.")
        return
 
    # Making the POST request to Power Automate flow
    response = requests.post(power_automate_url, headers=headers, json=transcript_data)
 
    if response.status_code == 200:
        st.success("Meeting Notes sent successfully for organizer's approval!")
        st.success("Check your mail once they approve.")
    else:
        st.error(f"Failed to send Meeting Notes. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        st.error(f"Response content: {response.content}")

After changing the scope, you will be able to trigger the power automate flow successfully.
